# How to reduce verobsity when dealing with lists and using mypy?

Tags: python, mypy

I was just writing this sort of thing at work and was wondering if there was any pythonic way to reduce the extraneous stuff related to list, iterator and set handling in Item.display().

Is there some more pythonic way to deal with the filtering and transformation in Item.display()?

Is there some way I could use different type to make typing easier?

```
import unittest
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Union, Tuple, List, Iterator

@dataclass
class Category:
    id: str
    name: str = field(compare=False)
    canonical: Union['Category', None] = field(compare=False)

    def __hash__(self)->int:
        return self.id.__hash__()

    def unalias(self)->'Category':
        #There could be more tests here
        if self.canonical:
            return self.canonical
        else:
            return self

    def display_str(self)->str:
        if self.id and self.name:
            return f'{self.id} [{self.name}]'
        else:
            return self.id


@dataclass
class Item:
    id: str
    categories: List[Category]


    def display(self,primary:Category)-> List[str]:
        """Unalias, dedup and sort for display."""
        if not self.categories:
            return []

        def unalias(secs:Iterator[Category])->Iterator[Category]:
            return map(lambda c: c.unalias(), secs) 

        def de_prim(secs:Iterator[Category])->Iterator[Category]:
            return filter(lambda c: c.id != primary.id, secs)

        def to_display(secs:List[Category])->List[str] :  
            return list(map(lambda c: c.display_str(), secs) )

        de_primaried = set(de_prim(unalias(iter(self.categories))))
        if not de_primaried:
            return []    
        return sorted(to_display(de_primaried))


class DoiTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        primary = Category('shirt', 'Shirts', None)

        cats = [Category('snow','Snowflakes',
                         Category('frozen_water','Frozen Water',None) ),
                Category('t-shirt','Tee Shirts', primary),
                Category('cheese','Yummy Cheese',None)]
        item = Item( 'ItemX', cats)
        self.assertEqual( item.display(primary) , ['cheese [Yummy Cheese]', 'frozen_water [Frozen Water]'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping out the mypy bits, it looks like this is effectively what you're doing?

```
def display(self, primary):
    return sorted(
        map(
            lambda c: c.display_str(), 
            set(
                filter(
                    lambda c: c.id != primary.id, 
                    map(
                        lambda c: c.unalias(), 
                        self.categories
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Unless there's a reason you'd want `categories` to have the value `None`, I'd initialize it to an empty list. Since `de_primaried` will always be a valid argument to map, even if it's empty, there's no need to check it and manually return an empty list.

You might want to consider building your return value in a couple of nested loops for readability (the one-off functions in there definitely aren't the way to go, in my opinion, particularly given the extra type clutter). Also, it's entirely possible I'm missing something, but there seem to be a couple of unnecessary `list()` and `iter()` calls in there.

Comment: Yes, that is effectively what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I'd like to know how to make these unnecessary list() and iter() calls unnecessary even under mypy checking.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for; if mypy is for some reason making them necessary, that seems very strange. I'm unfamiliar with that library, though, so I wouldn't know where to start with that.

Comment: Thanks for your help.